# Async issues with AWS SDK. Await not waiting

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, async-await

I'm having troubles while trying to upload images from device (React Native Expo). Upload itself goes well, but I depend on the response to get the publication URL, and I'm sending that info to my backend.

The problem is that uploading images is an async function, which requires to await for the answer, and that's not happening. Cannot figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
export async function uploadImageOnS3(file) {
    const s3bucket = new S3({
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
    Bucket: "",
    signatureVersion: "v4",
    });
    s3bucket.createBucket(() => {
    let contentDeposition = 'inline;filename="' + file.fileName + '"';

    const params = {
      Bucket: "",
      Key: file.fileName,
      Body: file.payload,
      ContentDisposition: contentDeposition,
      ContentType: file.type,
    };
    s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error in callback " + err);
      }
      console.log("success");
      return data;
    });
  });
}
```

Here I'm returning "data" object which contains all required info.

Here is the trouble:

```
async function startPostingProcess(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const validation = await validateGeoLocation(geoLocation);
    
    if (validation.data.message) {
     
      setMessage(validation.data.message);
    } else {
      const imageToUpload = await getImageFromDevice(images);
     const location = await uploadImageOnS3(imageToUpload) //Here "await" is not waiting
      const newPost= {
        postName,
        postDesc,
        postApproxLocation,
        geoLocation,
        uploadImage: location.Location //Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError
        author: userInfo.username,
      };
      
       await createPost(newPost);
      setMessage(POST_CREATED);  
    }
  }
```

As I said, upload goes well, and required data is consoled out, but only after Unhandled promise rejection

Not getting what I'm doing wrong, "uploadImageOnS" startPostingProcess is a async function which awaits to uploadImageOnS3, which is also a async function. I tried returning a Promise in uploiadImageOnS3 which resolves with required data but getting same behavior.

What's wrong here?

EDIT: Tried suggested approach so code looks as follows:

```
export async function uploadImageOnS3(file) {
    const s3bucket = new S3({
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
    Bucket: "",
    signatureVersion: "v4",
    });
    let contentDeposition = 'inline;filename="' + file.fileName + '"';

    const params = {
      Bucket: "",
      Key: file.fileName,
      Body: file.payload,
      ContentDisposition: contentDeposition,
      ContentType: file.type,
    }
      await s3bucket.createBucket().promise();
      const data = await s3bucket.upload(params).promise();
      return data;
  
    }
```

Now I'm getting  [Unhandled promise rejection: MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params]. But I can see how params.Bucket contains a string with my S3 Bucket's name.

Comment: You need to call `.promise()` on each AWS method and await that returned promise.

Comment: all your buckets are set to `""`

Comment: Yeh but just to post it here. Bucket property is filled with required bucket name in string format

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all AWS SDK methods return `AWS.Request` (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html)). You need to call `.promise()` method and `await` that returned promise.
You don't need to pass callback.

Your `uploadImageOnS3` become,

```
export async function uploadImageOnS3(file) {
  // skip

  await s3bucket.createBucket().promise();

  const params = /*skip*/;
  await s3bucket.upload(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: Hi Niyoko, thanks for your (really quick) reply! I changed the code as you suggested, but now I'm getting "[Unhandled promise rejection: MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params]"
I can clearly see that params.Bucket points to required data as I changed nothing when I refactored the code. I'll edit the main post. Any idea what could be wrong? First time messing with AWS

Comment: Your parameters is not valid according to the docs. I am not mentioning that because that is not your question here. Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) for more information or ask a new question and I will be happy to answer there.

Comment: How can that be possible? Uploading was working well before the refactor you suggested

Comment: I have no idea. Your bucket is empty string. Or that is purposely ommited?

Comment: It is purposely ommited in order to post it here. btw, I tried more approaches and I just discovered that passing s3bucket.upload as callback to s3.createBucket( ), I get same error BUT the image is uploading properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am guessing you have already fixed this however I noticed that in your function you have the Bucket attribute empty: ( Bucket: "" ) hence the error "Missing required key 'Bucket' in params". That attribute should be name of your bucket.